# What format for animated slideshow to post on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have a slide show created with OpenOffice. It is saved as an .odp file. What format should it be to post on Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

I think facebook did not support .odp format. I have listed the facebook supported format below. Please check the format that is feasible to convert.

- **Picture**: BMP, JPEG, JPG, PNG, TIFF
- **Video**: MPEG, MP4, AVI, DivX AVI, WMV, VOB, MOV, FLV, RM/RMVB, ASF
- **Music**: MP3, WAV, WMA, Sound tracks from CDs, Voice narrations &
  recordings